# how to send images file to the url?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Here is my code:

```
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "LiveUpdate.php";
    var sb = document.getElementById("LiveUpdate").value;
    var FirstName = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
    var images = document.getElementById("images").value;


    var vars = "update="+sb+"&FirstName="+FirstName+"&images="+images;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("success_insert").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("success_insert").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

I just want to send all the basic details like First name, Middle name, Last name, and the image. The problem is, I can send the First name, Middle name, and Last name, but I can't pass the image to the LiveUpdate.php endpoint.

What's going on?

Comment: Modern browsers all have javascript debuggers built in `(F12)` normally loads the debugger. Now you can debug your own code

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="file">` element stores `FileList` of `File` objects selected by user at `.files` property, the `.value` of element is set as a string. You can set `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data`, use `FormData()`, set `name` property of elements to query string keys, `.value` or `.files` property of `<form>` elements will be set at values of `FormData` object.

Call `event.preventDefault()` at `submit` event of `<form>`, pass `form` reference to `FormData()` constructor to set key, value pairs at `FormData` object.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <form id="form1" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
      First Name
      <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName">
      <br>Live Update
      <input type="text" name="LiveUpdate" id="LiveUpdate">
      <br>Image
      <input type="file" id="images" name="images" accept="image/*">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
    var form = document.getElementById("form1");

    form.onsubmit = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      function ajax_post(form) {
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
        var url = "/dev/null";
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
              var return_data = hr.responseText;
              //document.getElementById("success_insert").innerHTML = return_data;
            }
          }
          // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
        hr.send(new FormData(form)); // Actually execute the request
        // document.getElementById("success_insert").innerHTML = "processing...";
      }
      ajax_post(this)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i have a question in
hr.send(new FormData(document.querySelector("form")));
Where did you get the "form"?
because im having a problem right now. this is the error.

Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Yes, select the `<form>` element  that is parent element of `sb`, `Firstname`, `images`.

Comment: @KennethSuaverdez Not certain what issue is. See updated post, moved call to `FormData()` before `.send()`

Comment: When is `ajaxPost()` called?

Comment: Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @KennethSuaverdez See updated post. Check `Network` tab when submit `form`. Note `event.preventDefault()` call at `submit` event handler.

Comment: nothing really happened sir. the ajaxPost() just giving the error Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @KennethSuaverdez Have you tried stacksnippets? You can use `DevTools` or `Developer Tools` to view `POST` request at `Network` tab.

Comment: yes i Developer Tools but nothing is in There. no javascript error

Comment: Select `Network` tab, fill our form, submit form, select last request at `Name` panel, select `Headers`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: sir i copy your code and connect it to my LiveUpdate.php but still nothing happened

Comment: At stacksnippets, or `php`? Can you create a jsfiddle or plnkr including `javascript` you are trying? Stacksnippets posts a `FormData` object. Not sure what issue is.